# JdbcPagingItemReader union multiple queries

Tags: spring, union, paging, batch-processing

I am using Spring Batch. I have a SQL statement which is built up from multiple xml file elements. All of the results come from the same table, but each of the statements have a different XXX as keyValue.

I have extended both a JdbcCursorItemReader, where I use a setSql to set the sql String and this works fine. However performance isn't great and it can't be multithreaded. I then switched to extending a SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean and adding a thread pool executor to my tasklet and for one simple sql statement I have noticed a significant decrease in time.

What I need to know is how to use my complex sql with unions and the SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean, is this possible. Surely this component can deal with more than a simple select from where clause.

Comment: if it you are fetching from the same table you can try with OR conditions instead of unions